# How are membranes for Polymer electrolyte membrane electrolysis produced?

Tags: electrochemistry, polymers, electrolysis

[Polymer electrolyte membrane electrolysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer_electrolyte_membrane_electrolysis) is a process used for creating hydrogen with a thin metal membrane. This membrane is often includes a thin metal sheet of Platinum. My question is, how these ultra-thin membranes are produced?

Comment: Please be more clear. Are you wondering how thin platinum sheets are fabricated, specifically? Otherwise this appears to be a rather broad question. The technology undoubtedly has evolved and production methods might vary. References in the Wikipedia article you linked to provide some information on the subject, for instance https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037877531630012X?via%3Dihub

Comment: If it's Pt thin films you are interested in, there is this for instance: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0360319920312532